# Better Way to Remove Elements from a List?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going to have a unordered list (`<UL>`) of items.  Each item will have a delete button, which will make an ajax call & then remove the item from the list.  I have all the info I need to make the Ajax call, but I'm wondering the best way to let the user remove any item in the list.

My first thought is to dynamically assign each `<LI>` a unique class identifier & then use jquery's `remove()` on each element, but is there a better way?   I have a feeling my approach is somewhat ham-fisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to invent some unique class names (you meant unique identifiers, right? `id`, not `class`).

Just use the clicked button to find its parent `li`.

```
$('li .delete_button').click(function() {
  var that = this;
  $.post(url, data, function(data) {
    if(data.can_delete) {
      $(that).parent('li').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Haven't seen using `that` as a variable to store reference to `this` ))) Personally prefer `t`, but `that` just looks funny. I'd upvoted just because of such name if I hadn't answered too ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: You should upvote anyway, it's called 'sportsmanship' :-)

Comment: I'd better `.remove()` my answer and upvote yours. The question is too boring anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach at all.  Instead of using a class (which is slightly ham fisted) you could use dataset attributes, like `<li data-unique-id="">`, or even the `id`.

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function () {
   $.post('remove-script', 'id=' + this.id, function () {
      $(this).fadeOut(function () { $(this).remove(); });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>TEXT <input type="button" value="Delete" data-id="1" /></li>
  <li>TEXT <input type="button" value="Delete" data-id="2" /></li>
  <li>TEXT <input type="button" value="Delete" data-id="3" /></li>
</ul>
```

And scripts

```
$("ul li input").click(function() {
  //ajax call on $(this).data('id');
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1, delete li elements which's title are delete ...

```
$("ul li").remove("li[title==delete]");
```

2, delete the second li element

```
var $li=$("ul li:eq(1)").remove();
```

Comment: `this can let u delete li elements which's title are delete ...` --- not actually. This will delete **all** the items from the page. Regardless of what have been clicked